# Azure DevOps IP addresses

Tags: azure-devops

I have an application running on Web App that needs to communicate with Azure DevOps Microsoft hosted agent. I've set some IP restrictions to deny everything and now in the process of whitelisting agent's IPs. When I read [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#networking) it refers to weekly json that contains objects about everything what I need (CIDRs per region). I've parsed the json, added them to my allow list, however the agent's public IP address is not from the range mentioned in the json. The way I checked it was running bash task on the agent to `curl icanhazip.com`. Does anyone know if the list is complete or should I look somewhere else?

I.e. example in my case:

I use this data (since my ADO org is in West Europe):

```
{
      "name": "AzureDevOps.WestEurope",
      "id": "AzureDevOps.WestEurope",
      "properties": {
        "changeNumber": 1,
        "region": "westeurope",
        "regionId": 18,
        "platform": "Azure",
        "systemService": "AzureDevOps",
        "addressPrefixes": [
          "40.74.28.0/23"
        ],
        "networkFeatures": null
      }
    }
```

but the agent initiates connection from the IP: 20.238.71.171, which is not in any of the CIDRs privided by that json file (checked all other regions with ADO).

Any thoughts / help?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You would need to whitelist ALL ranges from, for instance, Azure West Europe. Those are a lot of different IP ranges, as Azure DevOps hosted agents do not have a service Tag.

Since this opens up your firewall to literally every VM running in West Europe, this is usually not really desired, as it is just a bit short of opening up your App to the entire world.

Hence, what people usually do is the following:

1. First task in a build job, fetch the public IP address of the executing build agent, using something like ipfy.org
2. Use AZ CLI to add this IP as a single IP allow rule to your app
3. Do your deployment etc
4. Remove the IP rule again

Comment: Ah, noted. I've done exactly what you explained right after posing this question, but though there is better way. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: self-hosted build agents would be the alternative. But that of course comes with a lot more management overhead

Comment: @evgeny what is the better way than this (except using self hosted agents) ? tnx

Comment: I did exactly what @silent described..

Comment: @evgeny, can you tell how did you do these steps in a separate answer or in this one

Comment: @silent - I must be missing something totally obvious. But if the job is running on the agent, then are you effectively **whitelisting the IP from the IP you are trying to whitelist**? Or does the AZ CLI bypass the access restriction?

Comment: @ayang yes, the difference here is control plane (ARM) vs data plane (the web app itself). You are setting IP restrictions via control plane which then apply to the data plane.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but since I end up here I thought of sharing the code that I used based on the proposed solution.

I used the Azure Cli [az keyvault network-rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/network-rule?view=azure-cli-latest) module to add and remove the Public Agent IP.

Sample of code:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: "Adding Virtual Agent Public Allowed IP Firewall list of KV."
  inputs:
    scriptType: "pscore"
    scriptLocation: "inlineScript"
    azureSubscription: $( azureSubscription )
    inlineScript: |
      $agentHostPublicIp = (Invoke-WebRequest ifconfig.me/ip).Content.Trim()
      Write-Output "Public IP of agent to add: $agentHostPublicIp"
      az keyvault network-rule add --name $(vg_vault_name) --ip-address $agentHostPublicIp --no-wait --resource-group $(vg_resource_group_name)

  - task: AzureKeyVault@2
    displayName: "Download from Azure Key Vault '$(vg_vault_name)' secrets."
    inputs:
      azureSubscription:$( azureSubscription )
      KeyVaultName: $(vg_vault_name)
      SecretsFilter: "*" # string. Required. Secrets filter. Default: *.
      RunAsPreJob: false

  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: "Removing Virtual Agent Public Allowed IP Firewall list of KV."
    inputs:
      scriptType: "pscore"
      scriptLocation: "inlineScript"
      azureSubscription: $( azureSubscription )
      inlineScript: |
        $agentHostPublicIp = (Invoke-WebRequest ifconfig.me/ip).Content.Trim()
        Write-Output "Public IP of agent to remove: $agentHostPublicIp"
        az keyvault network-rule remove --name $(vg_vault_name) --ip-address $agentHostPublicIp --no-wait --resource-group $(vg_resource_group_name)
```

As a next step you can use what ever secrets you have pulled from the vault.

Sample from the official documentation [Use Azure Key Vault secrets in Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

This solution assumes that the user is using Azure Public Agents and not Hosted Agents. In the case the user is using Hosted Agents then he simply needs to add once the public IP(s) of the Agent(s) and no need to remove them again.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean MS-hosted agent:
You should use AzureCloud service tag

The IP address ranges for the hosted agents are listed in the weekly file under AzureCloud., such as AzureCloud.westus for the West US region.

Docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#networking